# $|\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-t^{2}} e^{-(t/\lambda -x)^{2}} e^{-2\pi i w\cdot t}| dt \leq G(x,w), G\in L^{1} ? $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, fourier-analysis

Put $\lambda >0,$ and we define,

$$F_{\lambda}(x, w)= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-t^{2}} e^{-(t/\lambda -x)^{2}} e^{-2\pi i w\cdot t} dt;(x,w) \in \mathbb R^{2}$$
we note that, $F_{\lambda} \in L^{1}(\mathbb R^{2}).$

> **My Question is**: Can we expect to find, $G\in L^{1}(\mathbb R^{2})$ such that,
>   $$|F_{\lambda}(x, w)| \leq G(x,w); (x,w) \in \mathbb R^{2} ?$$
>   (Bit roughly speaking, how to dominate sequence functions uniformly by a $L^{1}-$ integrable function  )

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this solution is what you are looking for! First notice that

> $$ (t/\lambda-x)^2 \geq 0 \implies -(t/\lambda-x)^2 \leq 0 \implies e^{-(t/\lambda-x)^2}\leq 1. $$

and

> $$ |e^{-2\pi i w  t}| =1. $$

So we have

> $$ |F_{\lambda}(x, w)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-t^2}dt < \infty.  $$

Comment: thanks a lot;  I am looking for function, $G(x,w)$ such that, $G\in L^{ 1}(\mathbb R^{2});$ and it dominates $F_{\lambda};$ can we expect this ?

Comment: @DivyangBhimani: You can get a function $G(x)$. By the way why you need a function while your integral converges independently from $x$ and $w$?

Comment: @DivyangBhimani: Do you know what uniform convergence is?

Comment: Benghogbal; thanks for the attention; Bit roughly speaking, motivation behind this question is to solve this problem:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874798/int-mathbb-r2-int-mathbb-r-f-rt-y-f-rt-gt-x-e-2-pi-i ; Thanks,